# Difference between pd.merge() and dataframe.merge()

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I'm wondering what the difference is when you merge by `pd.merge` versus `dataframe.merge()`, examples below:

```
pd.merge(dataframe1, dataframe2)
```

and

```
dataframe1.merge(dataframe2)
```

Answer (score 9):

We've two functions at our disposal for almost the same task pandas.merge() and DataFrame.merge().

```
pandas.merge(left, right, how='inner', on=None, left_on=None, right_on=None, 
          left_index=False, right_index=False, 
          sort=False, suffixes=('_x', '_y'), copy=True, indicator=False, validate=None)

DataFrame.merge(right, how='inner', on=None, left_on=None, right_on=None, 
             left_index=False, right_index=False, 
             sort=False, suffixes='_x', '_y', copy=True, indicator=False, validate=None)
```

**Both look similar, what's the advantage of using one over the other?**

pd.merge() calls for df.merge, so df1.merge(df2) will give almost same results as pd.merge(df1, df2).

However, pd.merge() is **wrapping style** function and df1.merge() is **chaining style**, which makes the later easier to chain from left to right

E.g.,

```
 df1.merge(df2).merge(df3) 
 #looks better and readable [analogus to %>% pipeline operator in R] than 
 pd.merge(pd.merge(df1, df2), df3).
```

### Let's Look at a reproducible example

```
d1 = pd.read_html('https://worldpopulationreview.com/countries')
pop = d1[0]
print(pop.info(), '\n') #Data for 232 countries for 7 columns

pop.head(3)

d2 = pd.read_html('https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/median-age')
age = d2[0]
print(age.info(), '\n') #Data for 221 countries for 5 columns

age.head(3)

display('pd.merge(): ', pd.merge(pop, age), 'df.merge(): ', pop.merge(age))
```